# PHP7 - iconv not running easyapache4

Tags: centos

I have installed php with "--with-iconv" but I dont seem to see Iconv being enabled in the phpinfo()?

How can this be resolved?

- Centos 6.8
- EasyApache4
- PHP7.0

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing required modules using command line

```
yum install ea-php70-php-fileinfo
```